# how to download a file from s3 bucket with a temporary token in python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I have a django web app and I want to allow it to download files from my s3 bucket.
The files are not public. I have an IAM policy to access them.
The problem is that I do **NOT** want to download the file on the django app server and then serve it to download on the client. That is like downloading twice. I want to be able to download directly on the client of the django app.
Also, I don't think it's safe to pass my IAM credentials in an http request so I think I need to use a temporary token.
I read:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html

but I just do not understand how to generate a temporary token on the fly.
A python solution (maybe using boto) would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.whitneyindustries.com/aws/2014/11/16/boto-plus-s3-plus-sts-tokens.html

Comment: @NehalJWani actually the downloaded file has an error that says No AWSAccessKey was presented. I passed my AWSAccessKey in the url and passed the token in the header.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Boto (2), it should be really easy to generate time-limited download URLs, should your IAM policy have the proper permissions. I am using this approach to serve videos to logged-in users from private S3 bucket.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection('<aws access key>', '<aws secret key>')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')
key = bucket.get_key('mykey', validate=False)
url = key.generate_url(86400)
```

This would generate a download URL for key `foo` in the given bucket, that is valid for 24 hours (86400 seconds). Without `validate=False` Boto 2 will check that the key actually exists in the bucket first, and if not, will throw an exception. With these server-controlled files it is often an unnecessary extra step, thus `validate=False` in the example

---

In Boto3 [the API is quite different](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url):

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Generate the URL to get 'key-name' from 'bucket-name'
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'mybucket',
        'Key': 'mykey'
    },
    expires=86400
)
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. so does "validate" mean overwrite?

Comment: @max no, these are for download urls. If you omit validate (which defaults to `True`) then boto2 will actually check that the key exists, and throws an exception if the bucket does not contain the key.

Comment: what is the "mykey"? I tried it replacing mykey with my filename and it did not allow me to download.

Comment: assuming that "mykey" is the filename, I'm getting this error: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.

Comment: it is the name of the *key*. There are no "filenames" in S3. In your case, perhaps you should remove `validate=False` then.

Comment: And you're not to change the returned URL in any way.